# How to convert "Hours:Minutes:Seconds AM/PM"(UTC timezone) to the user's time zone in the format of "Hours:Minutes AM/PM" in Swift?

Tags: swift, date-formatting

The input string will always be in the Hours:Minutes:Seconds AM/PM format, and it will always be in the UTC Timezone (The string represents the sunrise time where the user is, but only in UTC). A few examples are:
10:3:30 AM,
2:40:01 PM,
12:0:04 AM

I want to convert the time to the user's timezone and then get rid of the seconds component, so that it is just "Hours:Minutes AM/PM"

So far, I think I can use
`var localTimeZoneAbbreviation: String { return TimeZone.current.abbreviation() ?? "" }`
to get the user's current timezone, but I still don't know how to convert the string to that timezone. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter). One instance to convert from your UTC time to a `Date` and another to convert from that `Date` to a localized `String`.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // set locale before format; good to use this locale for fixed date formats
formatter.dateFormat = "h:m:ss a"
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
let date = formatter.date(from: "10:3:30 AM")! // whichever input string you have

let localFormatter = DateFormatter() // time zone and locale default to system's
localFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a" // if you don't want a zero padding single digits then use "h:m a" 
let string = localFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Note the day/month/year will implicitly default to the default for the system, (I'm seeing January 1 2000) but you can presumably ignore that.

Comment: I'll try this out and let you know if it works. The examples are inconsistent for a reason: the hour and minute sections might be 1 or 2 digits, but the seconds will always have two digits. This is something I have no control over, unfortunately.